# Errror: INCORRECT NAMESPACE in Custom Sitemap Structure

Tags: sitemap.xml

I want to create custom site map for my site: https://adaway.info
, the problem is that when I write the whole thing, it gives an error of `Incorrect Namespaces on a number of lines`.

Can anyone explain how to get rid of this?

(P.S: For my convenience I have used yoast sitemap for now, but I'm really looking for a custom sitemap.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to be extremely careful to ensure that the schema and locations are exactly as this:

`http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9` - I once had
`http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9`
and it returned the same error that you are receiving. See if you can spot the trailing whitespace.

Here is an example using SimpleXML:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><urlset></urlset>');
$xml->addAttribute('xmlns','http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
$xml->addAttribute('xmlns:xmlns:xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$xml->addAttribute('xmlns:xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd');
```